# Omitting intercepts from coefplot of mblogit model

Tags: r

I am using coefplot() package to plot my coefficients from a multinomial model using mblogit().
I see from the coefplot vignette we can use intercept = FALSE to remove the incept from a plot. This works for my glmm lmer() model, but not for my multinomial mblogit() model.
Any thoughts on why?

Thank you!

Comment: Please provide some sample data from `dput()` along with your desired output

Comment: If the name of the intercept term of your fitted model is not the expected default ("Inntercept"), I believe you have to specify both `intercept = FALSE`  and a value for `interceptName` in your call to `coefplot`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the name of the intercept term of your fitted model is not the expected default ("(Intercept)"), I believe you have to specify both `intercept = FALSE` and a value for `interceptName` in your call to `coefplot()`.